# How to hide comments by default in Dropbox file viewer?

Tags: dropbox, comments

The comment bar takes space in Dropbox.

I hate manually hiding it every time; I want it to be hidden by default.

I did not find any button to hide the panel by default in Dropbox's settings. Dropbox's own user forum is also rather inactive.

How can you hide comments by default in Dropbox's file viewer in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. They are not working actively with the development of the product. I moved to *ownCloud* which is more robust and better developed than Dropbox if you have own Raspberry Pi server.